# Standard guarantees about moved-from container

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider following piece of code:

```
std::unordered_set<int> foo {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::unordered_set<int> bar = std::move(foo);
```

This is pretty straightforward example. My question is - is foo still "usable" (and hopefully empty) after moving data or is it UB or implementation specific behaviour when I call after this something like this:

```
foo.insert(1);//is it valild??
```

Comment: Did you mean to ask if `foo.insert(1);` is still valid?

Comment: @Barry yes, of course. Fixed it

Comment: Maybe I'm being thick but I don't see how "hopefully empty" is addressed by the allegedly duplicated question. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move isn't clear on this either